# Jquery dynamic validations html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

I'm working in `javascript/jQuery` forms filling and validation. However I have a following scenario that I want using `for-loops`.

I've 3 fields in one container, and I have total 4 containers, The first box is must, scha that the first item `input text "A"` should be validated. And second is radio button, having their respective input fields, so the check is must that which radio button is pressed and made that field validated and the other is not. Let the radio button is **Option B** and their respective input text boxes are **C and D**.

Now The rest of there have the same case when there activator check box is checked otherwise no validation. Let my checkBoxes are **X**. So my code is:

My Code is 70% working, don't know why. Also, I want to check it back, that if the checkboxes aren't clicked(such that unchecked after clicked) it removes all the validations for the upcoming containers.

I've my custom javascript function of validating check boxes names `checkRadio`and `makeRequire/makeUnrequire` that accepts an array of input and make all of them as said.

How can I implement the optimal solution for such scenario.

```
  for (var i = 1; i <=3; i++) {
        if (checkRadio("X-"+i))
        {
         for (var j = 2; j <=4; j++) {  
            for (var k = 1; k <=3; k++) {   
                  if (checkRadio("B"+j+"-1")) {
                    makeRequired(["C-"+k]);
                    makeUnRequired(["D-"+k]);
                } else if (checkRadio("B"+j+"-2")) {
                    makeUnRequired(["C-"+k]);
                  makeRequired(["D-"+k]);
                }

                };
                };
        }
```

My Id's conventions are, A-1, A-2, A-3 and A-4 for first text field.
B1-1 and B1-2 for respective text fields C-1 and D-1 for first container.